# Rails issue with new action/page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, view, action

I am building a basic news application. I have a "Posts" controller that controls the basic index, show, ect. I am attempting to add a new action with a corresponding view called "local_news". This page will feature news stories specially tagged to appear there.

Here is my link that leads to the new page, "local_new.html.erb":

```
<li><%= link_to "Local", posts_local_news_path, class: 'nav_link' %></li>
```

I get this error when I try to follow the link:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Extracted source (around line #74):

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_post
  @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
```

I am not sure what is going on here. This is my posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :new, :create]

# GET /posts
# GET /posts.json
def index
  @posts = Post.most_recent
end

def local_news

end

# GET /posts/1
# GET /posts/1.json
def show
   @posts = Post.most_recent
end

# GET /posts/new
def new
  @post = Post.new
end

# GET /posts/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /posts
# POST /posts.json
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post), notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /posts/1
# PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @post.update(post_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /posts/1
# DELETE /posts/1.json
def destroy
  @post.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end


private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_post
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :description, :photo, :ranking, :photo_file_name, :caption)
  end
end
```

Here is the routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'homes/show'

  devise_for :users
  resources :posts


  resources :homes, only: [:show]

  get 'posts/local_news', to: "posts#local_news"
  get "pages/contact" => "pages#contact"
  get "pages/about" => "pages#about"
  get "pages/election2016" => "pages#election2016"

  root "posts#index"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see     http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

The route appears when I run rake routes. But I can't get the page to open. Eventually, I want to have @posts go into the "local_news" page, just like they currently do with "index." But right now, I just want a basic html page with no ruby to open. It won't do it. Can someone help? I can't seem to find any documentation on this specific problem.

Comment: If anyone has a problem like this, I found out what the answer is. I had resources :posts before my route for the local_news page. If you put the local_news routes before the resources bit, it works.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with answering your own question :) Feel free to create and accept a proper answer, even if its to your own question, so that others can find the solution in future without having to read through comments.

Comment: Routes are searched from top to bottom so as soon as it finds the first matching route it calls out to ActionDispatch!